# remove all python versions

Tags: python

> **CAUTION**: All the below commands will COMPLETELY BREAK your OS.

I removed all version by doing :

```
sudo apt purge python-pip python-dev
 sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python*
 sudo rm -rf /etc/python*
 sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python*
 sudo rm -rf /usr/share/man/man1/python*
 sudo rm -rf /usr/share/python*
 sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pip*
```

Now when i try to install again :

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

It detects it is already installed ?

Any idea how to complety remove old versions ?

thanks

Comment: Congratulations. Looks like you may have thoroughly trashed your Ubuntu install. Apt depends upon Python3 to work properly. Also, NEVER use `rm` to remove packages that were installed by apt. Your command isn't *detecting* anything - apt is simply querying it's internal database...which no longer matches reality.

Comment: your best course of action is probably a re-install. make a backup of your personal files from the live session prior to reinstalling. you can do that without a format if needed but that will leave trails from the older install.

Answer (score 0):

The proper course of action after breaking your system so thoroughly is to re-install. You *might* be able to fix the system by running

```
dpkg -l | grep python     # see what the system think's is installed
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python* /tmp/   # get rid of the apt database files
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install *list-of-packages*
```

where the list-of-packages came from the first command.

Comment: I don't think APT will work and system is recoverable unless packages are manually downloaded from packages.ubuntu.com and installed using DPKG.

Comment: apt needs python. There is a way to reinstall apt without using apt or dpkg though but I can'f find how D:

Comment: This was the major issue in "might work". As @Kulfy indicated, you could try downloading the .deb files for python and installing them manually using `dpkg`.